# Best way to safely clear data in a singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I'm using a singleton called `CSAppData` to store data for my iPhone app. I'm storing an object called `CSInbox` in the singleton. When I logout of my app, I want to clear the data for that object.

Here is my singleton code, including the method for clearing the data:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.inbox = [[CSInbox alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (CSAppData *)appData {
    static CSAppData * appDataInstance;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if(!appDataInstance) {
            appDataInstance = [[CSAppData alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return appDataInstance;
}

+(void) clearData {
    CSAppData *appData = [CSAppData appData];
    appData.inbox = [[CSInbox alloc] init];
}
```

However, in one of my view controllers, in the `initWithCoder` method, I'm storing the inbox variable:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        self.inbox = [[CSAppData appData] inbox];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So, when the app logs out and the `clearData` method is called, the view controller is still pointing to the old `CSInbox` object. And even though I am initializing a new view controller and setting it to the root view controller (in the AppDelegate), like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MainTabControllerViewController *viewController = (MainTabControllerViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];
[self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
```

The one child view controller that has the `CSInbox` is never reinitialized, and is still pointing to that old CSInbox object. (I'm not sure why this is happening.)

So, what is the best way to solve this?

1. Change the `clearData` method in the singleton to just reset the properties of the `CSInbox` object, rather than alloc and init and new one?
2. Move the `self.inbox = [[CSAppData alloc] init];` to the `viewDidLoad` in the view controller class so it gets set properly upon the second login?
3. Change the logout function in the `AppDelegate` so that the root view controller and all other view controllers are released, so they will reinitialize upon the second login?

I'm leaning toward #1 or #3...

As requested, here is **CSInbox.h:**

```
@interface CSInbox : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *threads;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger newCount;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDate *lastUpdate;

-(void) setThreadsFromJSON:(NSDictionary *)json;

@end
```

And here is **CSInboxViewController.h**:

```
@interface CSInboxViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CSThreadViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *inboxTableView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) CSInbox *inbox;

@end
```

And **CSAppData.h**:

```
@interface CSAppData : NSObject {
    CSInbox *inbox;
}

@property(nonatomic,strong) CSInbox *inbox;

+ (CSAppData *)appData;
+ (void)clearData;

@end
```

Comment: So, it's not a true singleton object...How do you create a singleton class/object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer lies not in destroying the singleton object and recreating it, but to actually clear the instance variables within that singleton object.

You don't show the declaration of `[CSAppData inbox]`, but if it's an `NSMutableArray`, for example, then you can clear that, and any existing references to the singleton object can remain:

```
+(void) clearData {
    CSAppData *appData = [CSAppData appData];
    [appData.inbox removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: That would basically be option #1... I added the CSInbox.h code above. I could add a method in there to reset the data, and then call that method from the CSAppData singleton?

Comment: This was my initial thought as well - why realloc the item rather than just let arc eventually release it.

Comment: @TrevorGehman Yep.  However, complication increases if any UI elements contain the data (which is likely).  You might want to use notifications to signal changes to this data structure.

Comment: Well we are logging out at this point - you'd assume the object will be re-instantiated at next login.

Comment: Well that is the other (possibly separate) issue... why is the CSInboxViewController never being reinitialized after the logout/login process? I would think creating a new root view controller would release all the child view controllers... but that is not happening.

Comment: I actually found the answer to that as well. It IS being deallocated and reinitialized, I was just resetting the data AFTER the initWithCoder was being called, so it was pointing to the old data.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this, complying with the spirit of using a singleton, is having your view controllers access directly your singleton `inbox`, i.e.: `[CSAppData appData].inbox` instead of `self.inbox`. This is a bit wordier, but it would "magically" fix your issue.

If that is not acceptable to you, I would go with option #1 of those you list. Even better, I would make the `inbox` in the singleton a singleton itself, or make sure it is never replaced by another instance.

EDIT:

Another approach you have, is using KVO in your controller so that it gets notified when the `inbox` object has changed. Don't know if it is quite worth it, but could be used.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I thought it was best practice to pass data to a view controller, rather than having a view controller access data somewhere else...

Comment: I see your point, though you are using a singleton as a way to orderly access your data. This is kind of a basic design choice in your app, and I do not think it is bad practice sticking with it (and you also see it is the cleanest way to handle this). On the other hand, someone would say that using a singleton in the first place is bad practice, because of the dependencies it creates.