# Clear All View Controllers On Logout

Tags: ios, swift

I'm noticing that when a user logs out, all of the previous view controller objects are still stored in memory

current code in the logout page:

```
 @IBAction func LogOutClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain!)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_loginpage", sender: self)

}
```

current code on home page:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);


    MyVariables.prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let isLoggedIn:Int = MyVariables.prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int

    //not logged in
    if (isLoggedIn != 1)
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
    }
        //logged in
    else
    {
      // Start Filling objects with data
    }
}
```

The Logout button is on a separate view controller than the view controllers I'm trying to clear from memory and remove all the objects from

Comment: please, provide code from your controller. it seems that you have some blocks/variables that own your controller

Comment: im not using core data, however I am using structs to store my variables

Comment: Is there a way I can just loop through all controllers and release them? Or is there a better way of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150372/best-way-to-safely-clear-data-in-a-singleton). Although it is in reference to singletons, it might help:

> I think the answer lies not in destroying the singleton object and recreating it, but to actually clear the instance variables within that singleton object.
>
> You don't show the declaration of `[CSAppData inbox]`, but if it's an `NSMutableArray`, for example, then you can clear that, and any existing references to the singleton object can remain:
>
> ```
> +(void) clearData {
>     CSAppData *appData = [CSAppData appData];
>     [appData.inbox removeAllObjects];
> }
> ```

The question might have to be read to get some context for the code, but this variation might work:

```
func init() -> AnyObject {
    self = super()
    if self {
        self.inbox = CSInbox()
    }
    return self
}

class func appData() -> CSAppData {
    static var appDataInstance: CSAppData
            if !appDataInstance {
            appDataInstance = CSAppData()
        }

    return appDataInstance
}

class func clearData() {
    var appData: CSAppData = CSAppData.appData()
    appData.inbox.removeAllObjects()
}
```

I replaced the `clearData` function with the right one, vs. having the old function in there.

`CSInbox`. You might be able to ignore this, but I'm not sure. I think this is replaced by a class with your struct in it

```
class CSInbox: NSObject {
    var threads: [AnyObject]?

    var newCount: Int?

    var lastUpdate: NSDate?

    func setThreadsFromJSON(json: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    }
}
```

`CSInboxViewController` is replaced by your view controller(s)

```
class CSInboxViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CSThreadViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var inboxTableView: UITableView!

    var inbox: CSInbox?  // <=== This is replaced with variables containing your class(es)
}
```

This is the `CSAppData` class:

```
class CSAppData: NSObject {
    var inbox: CSInbox?  // <=== This is replaced with variables containing your class(es)

    class func appData() -> CSAppData {
    }

    class func clearData() {
    }
}
```

I will continue updating this answer as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace app delegate's window.rootViewController property as your login property (but you can't get animation)

If your root view controller is navigationController then first call performSegueWithIdentifier and after log in view has been appeared try this
 in viewDidAppear function of log in view controller.

And you also should make sure there are any strong  holden references to previous view controllers in your code.

```
    navigationController?.viewControllers = [self]
```